# Sencha cmd build error

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I am struggling for building a Sencha application so need ideas how to build it quickly. I will give you some background about the issue. 
I am working on a hybrid app which is built on sencha framework . The app is ready for deployment. This package will be used to upload it in phonegap to create ipk/apk files.

Problem : I got stuck in building process of application. As per sencha touch documentation, we can do it by running following this command:

```
Sencha app build package
```

However getting a compile error stating ruby dependency. I Installed ruby however the error still persists.

I suppose I am having conflicts with the Sencha tools versions. I tried with Sencha CMD 2.0.0  and Sencha touch 2.0.1.1 versions but nothing happened. Then I upgraded both of them to Sencha CMD 5.0 and Sencha touch 2.3.1 but same results.

Questions:
1. Do we require anything else except Sencha CMD and Sencha touch?
2. How to upgrade application to latest versions?

Comment: Please be more specific what version(s) you're using as different Sencha Cmd versions have different requirements. For 2.1.0 you should be able to find all the information you need from Sencha Touch [Introduction to Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.0/#!/guide/command) document. (I'm currently running Senha Touch 2.3.1 builds in a Vagrant Linux without any issues, so I can say nothing about 2.1.0.)

Answer (score 0):

Idk if my answer will take you in the right direction or not but when I first started and wanted to make changes with stuff involving ruby I had to use the CMD with ruby that gets installed when you install ruby. Its pretty much the same everything but supports ruby. I couldnt do a lot of things in the regular CMD.

Answer (score 0):

please specify more detail i am not getting but if you want to upgrade your app use first go to your application path and type "sencha app upgrade"